# Adjust this regex to remove ":" from matches

Tags: python, regex

I've written a very long, very specific regex to match any Japanese text in a file. Right now I'm testing it on json files and one of the problems I'm running into is trying to exclude a specific string `":"` while avoiding removing `:` from possible matches.

Regex: `(?<=[\"])[―一-龠ぁ-ゔァ-ヴーａ-ｚＡ-Ｚ０-９々〆〤～ｾｸﾊﾗﾟ゛！？＋（）【】『』←→↓↑←→、<>…･・。◎■◆×★=　”0-9A-Za-z.?!:;&/^%$#@*_+\-\\\[\]\(\)\"\'\ ]+(?=[\"])`

Line: `"8": { "name":"礼礼礼礼礼礼", "礼礼礼:name礼":"礼礼礼", "M1":"", "M2":"礼 礼礼礼 礼礼 礼礼礼", "S1":""},`

Expected Matches: `8` `name` `礼礼礼礼礼礼` `礼礼礼:name礼` `礼礼礼` `M1` `M2` `礼 礼礼礼 礼礼 礼礼礼` `S1`

Actual Matches: `8` `name":"礼礼礼礼礼礼` `礼礼礼:name礼":"礼礼礼` `M1":"` `M2":"礼 礼礼礼 礼礼 礼礼礼` `S1":"`

Edit:
Forgot to mention this but it also needs to be able to handle escaped quotes. i.e `"礼礼礼礼礼礼\"礼礼礼礼礼礼礼礼礼\"礼礼礼"`

Please note I'm interested in using this regex in multiple filetypes, not just json, which is why I'm not simply using a key/value regex. Though that would probably make things much easier.

Comment: If you mean you want to match `"` that are escaped with a backslash, you may use ``"((?:[―一-龠ぁ-ゔァ-ヴーａ-ｚＡ-Ｚ０-９々〆〤～ｾｸﾊﾗﾟ゛！？＋（）【】『』←→↓↑←→、<>…･・。◎■◆×★=　”0-9A-Za-z.?!:;&/^%$#@*_+[\]()\'" -]|\\.)*?)"``, see https://regex101.com/r/Wubpom/2. However, JSON parsing with regex is not recommended.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew That works nicely, thank you. If you don't mind, can you explain the regex to me a bit for future reference. Also yeah I normally wouldn't, but I'd rather not have to rewrite the whole script to support json if I can help it for now.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you implement another class for any file type you want to read. Also I'd recommend using whatever tools are available for you that let you avoid writing regex like this.

That being said you could use a non-greedy quantifier with you existing regex and simply drop the elements you don't need.

Your regex (non-greedy):

```
(?<=\")[―一-龠ぁ-ゔァ-ヴーａ-ｚＡ-Ｚ０-９々〆〤～ｾｸﾊﾗﾟ゛！？＋（）【】『』←→↓↑←→、<>…･・。◎■◆×★=　”0-9A-Za-z.?!:;&/^%$#@*_+\-\\\[\]\(\)\"\'\ ]+?(?=[\"])
```

would result in several matches of `:`, which you might want to drop if that's a viable option.

Comment: Forgot to mention this in the post but it needs to also be able to handle escaped quotes. Also you are very correct, I should really in the future start scraping based on file type haha.